# Показать пользовательскую форму выбора в окне быстрого просмотра WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я использую код, который на странице создания/редактирования товара показывает флажок «Roast Level». Когда менеджер нажимает на этот флажок, на странице отдельного продукта появляется поле выбора, позволяющее клиенту выбрать «Roast Level».

При выборе товара и добавлении его в корзину, выбранное значение появляется в самой корзине. Это значение также отображается на странице оформления заказа, на странице «Спасибо», в уведомлении по электронной почте и на странице редактирования заказа в панели администратора.

Вот этот код:

```
// Display Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'roast_custom_field_add');

function roast_custom_field_add() {
    global $post;

    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
            array(
                    'id' => '_roast_checkbox',
                    'label' => __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce'),
                    'description' => __('Enable roast level', 'woocommerce')
            )
    );
}

// Save Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'roast_custom_field_save');

function roast_custom_field_save($post_id) {
    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    $roast_checkbox = isset($_POST['_roast_checkbox']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_roast_checkbox', esc_attr($roast_checkbox));
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
*Display Select Box
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_roast_custom_field', 0 );
function add_roast_custom_field() {
    global $product;

    // If is single product page and have the "roast_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if ( is_product() && $product->get_meta( '_roast_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

        echo '<div class="roast_select">';

        $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'roast_custom_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Roast Level'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Please select',
                'Blue'  => 'Blue',
                'Rare'  => 'Rare',
                'Medium Rare'   => 'Medium Rare',
                'Medium'    => 'Medium',
                'Medium Well'   => 'Medium Well',
                'Well Done' => 'Well Done'
            )
        ), '' );
        echo $select;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Add as custom cart item data
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 21 );
function add_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['roast_custom_options'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['roast_option'] = wc_clean( $_POST['roast_custom_options'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
---------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'roast_custom_field', 10, 21 );
function roast_custom_field( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( isset($cart_item['roast_option']) ) {
        $item_name .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>' . __("Roast Level", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['roast_option'] . '</div>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Display roast custom fields values under item name in checkout
---------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 21 );
function roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['roast_option']) ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>' . __("Roast Level", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['roast_option'] . 'гр.</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Save chosen slelect field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_product_fitting_color', 10, 21 );
function save_order_item_product_fitting_color( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['roast_option']) ) {
        $key = __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce');
        $value = $values['roast_option'];
        $item->update_meta_data( $key, $value ,$item->get_id());
    }
}   

add_action('wp_footer','add_footer_script');
function add_footer_script(){
    ?>
    <script>
       jQuery('#roast_custom_options').on('change',function(){
           var roast_level = jQuery(this).val();
           /*console.log(roast_level); */
           var button = jQuery(this).closest('form').find('.add_to_cart_button'); console.log(button); 
           jQuery(button).attr('data-roast_custom_options',roast_level);
        });

    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Я пытаюсь добавить форму выбора «Roast Level» в окно быстрого просмотра, в файл [content-product-quick-view.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7NtSBhJFFFX1vDZzUf_66JCNvSs6BLq/view?usp=sharing) дочерней темы.

При добавлении кода появились ошибки. Либо сама форма не отображается, либо кнопка «Добавить в корзину» исчезает.

Вот код формы:

```
// If is single product page and have the "roast_checkbox" enabled we display the field
if ( $product->get_meta( '_roast_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

    echo '<div class="roast_select">';

    $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'roast_custom_options', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Roast Level'),
        'required'      => false,
        'return'       => false,
        'options'   => array(
            ''      => 'Please select',
            'Blue'  => 'Blue',
            'Rare'  => 'Rare',
            'Medium Rare'   => 'Medium Rare',
            'Medium'    => 'Medium',
            'Medium Well'   => 'Medium Well',
            'Well Done' => 'Well Done'
        )
    ), '' );
    echo $select;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Возможно сам код формы неправильный или неполный для этого PHP файла. Хотя action корректный и на отдельной странице товара все работает. Очень прошу вашей помощи в этом вопросе.

Comment: is_product() проверяет является ли текущая страница страницей товара (single-product). Уберите проверку и все должно заработать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я сделал так if ( $product->get_meta( '_roast_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) { Форма выбора появилась, но данные выбора не записываются и в корзине не показываются. Хотя на самой странице товара, этот же код отлично работает.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Добавил ссылку на php файл.

Comment: Я также оставил `$GLOBALS ['product'] = $product;` в PHP файле и удалил `global $product;` у своего кода. Но к сожалению, проблема не решилась.

Comment: Посмотрите в исходном коде, ваши значения вообще в форме находятся? По моему вы их просто выводите вне формы и при отправке они теряются.

Comment: Хм. Тогда почему все корректно работает на отдельной странице товара?

Comment: Потому что вы хуком добавляете их в форму перед кнопкой купить. А в попап  просто вставляете вне формы судя по коду. Проверку is_product()  из `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` убрали?

Comment: Да, проверку `is_product()` убрал. И как мне тогда быть? Файл content-product-quick-view.php не подхватывает форму из functions.php, поэтому приходится ставить ее напрямую в файл.

Comment: Уверены что не подхватывает? Уберите вообще проверку из хука woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button выведите какой нибудь простой текст в нем

Comment: Удалил форму из content-product-quick-view.php. В functions.php вообще убрал проверку if, если вы об этом. Оставил просто форму. На отдельной странице товара все по прежнему корректно работает. А в окне быстрого просмотра форма вообще не показывается.
Как вариант, убрал проверку в обоих файлах, на странице норм, в окне форма также не работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104387/discussion-between--and-dmitry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените ваш скрипт в `add_footer_script` на этот:

```
( function( $ ) {
   $( document ).ready( function() {
       $(document).on('change', '#roast_custom_options' ,function() {
           $('.add_to_cart_button').data('roast_custom_options', this.value)
       });
   });
 }( jQuery ) );
```

Вы передаете кастомное значение через data атрибут плюс т.к. данные грузятся через ajax нужно подписываться через контейнер или документ, иначе событие не будет срабатывать.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Все работает!